# Not Able to write data to a file when i am executing a lua script from redis with --eval option

Tags: lua, redis

In a Lua script, i am making some redis calls and also want to write some text data to a file as well. 
But when I am executing this lua script from redis using '--eval', it is not able to recognize 'io' or 'require' libraries and hence not able to execute.
Please if you can tell me if there is a way that i can write data to a file in lua when i am calling lua script from redis.

Note : command that i am executing : ' /opt/redis/src/redis-cli -p 6379 --eval test.lua '

in test.lua, it fails in line : " file = io.open("output.txt", "a") "
it shows me the error message : *Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'io'*

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about the use of Lua in Redis - it is under the [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) command.

Specifically, note that Redis' Lua is sandboxed and provides only a subset of the libraries. The`io` library is not a part of this subset.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply.  Yes, I have gone through the documentation that you mentioned, also this documentation as well https://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/  
I want to ask if there is any known way, so that I can make this 'io' library a part of Redis' Lua. 
Also, for information, i have installed lua separately in my machine from latest available RPMs.

Comment: The libraries are omitted intentionally for simplicity, predictability and security purposes. The only way to bring them in is to fork Redis' source code and change it.